# Exchange EWS ID conversion

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am trying to build an EWS (via SOAP - it's a PHP app, no .net!) application that looks up the appointments of an arbitrary user and then looks up, if possible, the appointment details.

I use the `GetUserAvailability` call and get `CalendarEvent`s back from it. So far so good, for events where I have view permission in Outlook too I get a `CalendarEventDetails` block inside the `CalendarEvent`. The `ID` however is nothing I can use in a subsequent `GetItem` call:

- ID from `CalendarEventDetails`: `00000000D18EFE3E27D8FA498176E18417AF9E590700B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800000000010D0000B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800008765890B0000`
- ID from the `CalendarItem` retrieved by a `FindItem` call (on the Calendar folder of the target user): `AAMkAGM5ODcxMzhjLTRkMGYtNDVmNC1iOTc5LTMyNWIyZTJhNWVjZABGAAAAAADRjv4+J9j6SYF24YQXr55ZBwCyqcZbY7fXS5AoQjye609oAAAAAAENAACyqcZbY7fXS5AoQjye609oAACHZYkLAAA=`

When I base64-decrypt the `FindItem` ID and convert it to hex, the `FindItem` id seems to consist of some header, a UUID and the ID from `CalendarEventDetails`.

What do I need to do to use a `CalendarEventDetails` ID with a `GetItem` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > 00000000D18EFE3E27D8FA498176E18417AF9E590700B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800000000010D0000B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800008765890B0000

This Id is the HexEntryId of the calendar appointment so it needs to be converted to an EWSId using the ConvertId operation in EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb799665(v=exchg.150).aspx . You will need to convert from Type HexEntryId to EWSid eg

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:ConvertId DestinationFormat="EwsId">
        <m:SourceIds>
          <t:AlternateId Format="HexEntryId" Id="00000000D18EFE3E27D8FA498176E18417AF9E590700B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800000000010D0000B2A9C65B63B7D74B9028423C9EEB4F6800008765890B0000" Mailbox="user@domain.com" />
        </m:SourceIds>
      </m:ConvertId>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```